# Center text with white-space: nowrap;

Tags: html, css, user-interface, whitespace, nowrap

I'm trying to center my title so I used `white-space: nowrap;` so it didn't stack and it appeared in one line but now it won't center. So there is the CSS code for the title and the appearance of it is fine, the only problem is that, instead of appearing centered, it starts from the center, and it keeps going right. So like, instead of "   Meet The Seekers    ", it does "      Meet the Seekers"

My code snippet is:

```css
.section-title {
  font-size: 4rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: black;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
  clear: both;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="about-top">
  <h1 class="section-title">Meet the <span>SEE</span>kers</h1>
  <p>We are a team of young entrepreneurs, who decided it was time to modernize the way we search the web. A diverse group of unexpected talents came together to make SEE-Tool available to every web user.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You want to center the `section-title` in the page?

Comment: Yes, I wanted it to be centered and on one line, but inline-block wasn't enough to get it in one line, so I used nowrap, and now it's just stuck on the side.

Comment: You may try my solution, I am sure it will solve issue, if not let me know by attaching more information

Comment: Your solutions did solve some of the centering problem, but now it cuts the text short.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you have `justify-content: center` in your code as it does not do anything there. You also don't need `inline-block` as `span` tag is not block element.

You may remove the `display` property and add `text-align: center`, so it will be centering your `h1` tag.

```css
.section-title {
  font-size: 4rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: black;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="about-top">
  <h1 class="section-title">Meet the <span>SEE</span>kers</h1>
  <p>We are a team of young entrepreneurs, who decided it was time to modernize the way we search the web. A diverse group of unexpected talents came together to make SEE-Tool available to every web user.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It does sort of center it but instead of showing the full thing it just cuts it, so now it reads "    Meet the seek   "

Comment: Can you share your full code? I'm confused why you have that result. Probably you set some different code somewhere.

Comment: I have updated the code, I think your previous codes were doing that behavour. Try again.

Comment: That is the only part of the code that affects the title, the rest is for the content, but is you think it's necessary then sure.

Comment: Try my updated code. Let see same thing happens.

Comment: That works, but it went back to putting the test on top of each other so instead of being one line it does: Meet The (enter) Seekers

Comment: I guess it's because of the responsiveness. It's displaying in a single line for me.

Comment: There is something else can be causing that. Where do you test it? If it is on mobile of course you cannot show 4rem text in one line.

Answer (score 0):

just use text-align:center

```css
.section-title {
      
      font-weight: 300;
      color: black;
      margin:0 auto;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
      text-align:center;
      
      
      
      }
```

```html
<div class="about-top">
      <h1 class="section-title">Meet the <span>SEE</span>kers</h1>
      <p>We are a team of young entrepreneurs, who decided it was 
        time to modernize the way we search the web. A diverse group 
        of unexpected talents came together to make SEE-Tool available 
        to every web user.</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: That's what I'm doing, but I still can get it to be in one line.

Comment: are you trying to ge "MEET THE SEEKERS" on one line?  Get rid of the font size.  try snippet again